# Создание страницы в активной теме Wordpress через плагин

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Необходимо при активации плагина создавать страницу с ярлыком `slug` в админке и её шаблон в директории активной темы (т.е. файл с названием `page-slug.php`).
Создаю страницу в админке так

```
$post_data = array(
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_name'     => 'schedule',
    'post_title'    => 'Страница с расписанием',
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 2,
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( wp_slash($post_data) );
```

Дальше интереснее, каким образом создай файл в активной теме или как привязать файл из плагина к странице в теме?

В голове есть способ, на подобии, что снизу (но кажется есть более правильный). Создать файл в директории с плагином и записать его в нужную тему (но тут какая-то дичь и я не могу записать новый файл)

```
$c = file_get_contents('page-schedule.txt');
file_put_contents('page-schedule.php', $c);
```

p.s. если данный способ имеет место быть, то как узнать директорию активной темы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютный путь к папке активной темы, неважно, родительской или дочерней, можно получить с помощью

```
$path = get_stylesheet_directory();
```

Полученная строка не содержит закрывающий слеш.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так

```
$c = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'page-schedule.txt' );
file_put_contents( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page-schedule.php', $c);
```

Comment: Ну, то есть прочитали мой ответ и перефразировали в свой. Конгениально.

Comment: В принципе да, но у меня какая то дичь была, не записывался файл, выдавало что-то на подобии такого "Плагин произвёл при активации 270 символов неожиданного вывода". Решилось почти само собой (так и не понял что это было, что за эдакая ошибка). А так да, вы натолкнули меня на мысль, что нужно путь было до файла в плагине дописать и помогли с путем до темы.